# Execution failed for app:preDexDebug error sending mail using java mail

Tags: java, android, email

Error that iam getting :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.icreate.icreate"
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions{
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6}
    packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.github.timlian:android-javamail:3258af8228'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')

}
```

Comment: add  defaultConfig {
        
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `multiDexEnabled`

```
defaultConfig {

   // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

For more info please have a look at:

[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @VishakhaJoshi Glad to help .Move ahead .