# Weird error after importing project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, noclassdeffounderror

Since some time I'm was developing Android app in Eclipse (important: settings in Eclipse: Project Build Target: API 19). Yesterday I've imported project to Android Studio. After some problems with dependencies (my app uses a few external libraries) I was able to run app. There is part of my build.gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 22
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Unfortunatelly when I run it on my phone with Android 4.4.4 it throws strange error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.settings.Setting
```

Setting is my class in app module (main module) so how is it possible?

When I run app in AVD with Android 6.0 it works fine!

When I change compileSdkVersion to 21 it runs on phones with Android 5.0 (emulated or physical) but I can't change to lower compileSdkVersion because one of the dependencies - https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry - is using compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1' and with older version it shows xml file errors in this library.

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:
I've changed some lines in gradle files and removed CreditCardEntry lib and now I'm getting error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
```

when I'm initializing Facebook SDK:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

in main Activity.

---

EDIT2:
I've added Facebook SDK library from repository and above error is solved but my old error is back:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.settings.Setting
```

Comment: You should set the target version as high as possible regardless.

Comment: I've changed that but problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Download the library.jar file and copy it to your /libs/ folder inside your application project.

Open the build.gradle file and edit your dependencies to include the new .jar file:

Now got to your gradle path and through command prompt clean it.

Comment: I've changed some lines in gradle.build and removed CreditCardEntry library and now I'm getting error: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
throws when I'm initializing Facebook SDK:
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
in main Activity

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. The problem was improper initialization of MultiDexApplication. I used this topic to solve it: [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)