# Android - App crashes on Pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services, proguard

My app is running well on Lollipop devices but it keep crashing on prior to version Lollipop.
I have simply implemented a banner add in my application with the following code through google documention

```
    // Request for Ads
           AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                  // Add a test device to show Test Ads
                 .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                 .build();

         // Load ads into Banner Ads
         mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

using

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

**manifest**

```
  <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <activity
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden
   |orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

**Error**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.app.aggro, PID: 13257
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: 
  com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzv
 E/AndroidRuntime: at   
 com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider
.onCreate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders
(ActivityThread.java:4589)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication
 (ActivityThread.java:4522)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:825)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at   
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main
(Native Method)
```

My Gradle file is

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 buildscript {
     repositories {
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
         classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
     }
 }
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     maven { url   
 "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"}
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url   
     "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
     maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }
 }
android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.app.aggro"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-
android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    dexOptions{
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
     }
  }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.0.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
     }
     compile('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.1.0@aar') {
         transitive = true
    }


    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
     }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
     compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
      compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.11'
     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
     compile 'com.jpardogo.googleprogressbar:library:1.2.0'
      compile 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.0.0-  
 SNAPSHOT'
     compile project(':storage')
     compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
     compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
      compile files('libs/activeandroid-3.1-beta.jar')
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
      compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
      compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.2.0'
  }
```

Please help me out to get out from this problem.

Comment: check if `Google Play Services` is available as library in project before using `AdRequest`

Comment: Yes i already included that by 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

and it is working in Lollipop but it keep crashing on Kitkat

Comment: post your gradle file.

Comment: i Have posted my gradle file

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way i found the soultion

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After expanding more than a hour on problem, I found that I have to do some modification in `MyApplication` Class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register with Active Android
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

I have overriden the `attachbaseContext` method and all works fine now.

Comment: where is MyApplication class in our Android Studio project?

Comment: You need to create one . Just create a simple java class and extends it from Application class as i did you can see in my answer and override the attachBaseContext method.Also include dependency in your app build gradle file compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'                                                         .And in manifest application tag include the class like this android:name=". Your class name"

Answer (score 5):

+) Building Apps with Over 65K Method will cause this Error.

+) When your application and the libraries it references reach a certain size ( **DEX file** of your application can have total number of **methods upto 65,536** including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code), you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.

+) To resolve it, include **Multidex Configuration** in your ***build.gradle*** like the highlighted one in picture, along with this override the **attachBaseContext(Context base)** method in your Application class with the below content.

```
public class YourParentApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
 }
}
```

Add this in you Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourParentApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/radiius_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
```

For more information about Multidex refer these site:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should lower the API in your AndroidManifest.xml
Lollipop is API 21.

Check this out: [API Levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)
Example:

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: can you explain little more because i have already lower the
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>

Answer (score 0):

reduce your minSdkversion to that version you want to give support

in gradle file of your project

As below

**minSdkVersion 10**