# android application suddenly stop working when change testing device

Tags: android, debugging, exception, runtime-error, device

I was working in android device with no problem

but once I try to test my application on another device I got the following exception in the start of the app

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.forsale.forsale, PID: 9040
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzt
            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4887)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:142)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know what is the problem exactly and why it is happening now, although it is working in other devices

Comment: Check this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035867/android-app-crashes-on-pre-lollipop-devices). It has reported same error like yours.

Comment: @DhavalPatel Thanks a lot, it really solve the problem, Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - App crashes on Pre-Lollipop devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035867/android-app-crashes-on-pre-lollipop-devices)