# Application crashes using multidex and google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

This is my first application. I tried to add Admob which requires google play services and Multidex support So I added those projects also.

My application is running fine in Android 5.1 but crashing in Android 3.2

I understand the error as it is trying to load some classes but not finding them in google play services (I think so don't know exactly).

```
    android minSdkVersion="13"
    android targetSdkVersion="21"
```

How can I fix ?

Logcat:

```
11-16 08:31:44.365: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-16 08:31:44.457: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzap
11-16 08:31:44.465: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
11-16 08:31:44.815: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.zzc', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.zzl.zza
11-16 08:31:44.835: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq.<init>
11-16 08:31:44.945: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbk', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig.zzG
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzc.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzf.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.zzdb(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.zzda(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at file_handler.bep_file_handle_activity.display_add(bep_file_handle_activity.java:78)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at file_handler.bep_file_handle_activity.onCreate(bep_file_handle_activity.java:53)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-16 08:31:45.155: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 08:31:51.885: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>
11-16 08:31:51.955: E/dalvikvm(392): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzoI
```

Comment: How do you add google play services library to your project?! --- And second question: Did  you add support library to your project!?

Comment: From add new android project->copy files to workspace->Right click to project->properties->Android from there I added libraries.

Comment: Only Multidex project I added from Extras->Support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To add google play services library**, you shouldn't copy jar file to your project; You should import google play services library project to your project. How?

1. Copy whole google play services to your workspace. (google play services library project path is:

   /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
2. Import google play services library to your project. Right click on your android project. Goto properties. Choose Android on the left panel. Click on Add and browse the library project. Select the same. Click ok and apply

**To add some jar to your project**:

1. Copy jar file to libs folder
2. Right click on your android project. Goto properties. Choose Java Build Path on the left panel. on Libraries tab, press "Add jars..." button and browse for added jar file, then apply and ok.

**UPDATE:**

**To add multidex support to your project**:

[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Please add latest support library v4.

**To add support library v4 automatically**:

In eclipse: Right click on your android project -> Android tools -> Add support library.

Comment: @BharatSharma is support-library-v4 up to date? Please see my updated answer.