# How to use Google Analytics in Android app with over 65K methods

Tags: android, google-analytics

[Building Apps with over 65K methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) requires the following in the manifest:

```
  <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
  </application>
```

[Using Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) needs the following in the manifest:

```
  <application
        ...
        android:name="AnalyticsApplication">
        ...
  </application>
```

How can these two be reconciled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `MultiDex.install` in your application class?

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

It works fine for me without changing the app name in the manifest.
See [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library) for more info.

Edit:

You can create a new class that extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
  private Tracker mTracker;

  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
      super.attachBaseContext(base);
      MultiDex.install(this);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
   * @return tracker
   */
  synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
  }
}
```

Then in your manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="AnalyticsApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for my ignorance.  Where do I add this code?  I assume this does not mean that I have to add this code to every class.

Comment: No, you can add it only in your Application class. I updated my answer. Let me know if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the editing. Is this class used anywhere else in the app?  In other words, is this just a sort of dummy class not used by any activities of the app?

Comment: It's the main application class. it has callbacks for application level lifecycle. e.g. onCreate() is called when an app is created. Roughly speaking, Activity represents a screen but Application represents the whole app. Anyway, you can treat it as a dummy class if you don't have any global variables/methods. more info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience.  Everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

1) Enable `multidex` in `build.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // your stuff
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

2) Need to subclass `Application` and add this

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```