# Adding dependencies to Google play service and Google+ sign in

Tags: google-play-services, google-signin

I actually have the next dependencies in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

When I added the last (needed to implement GCM) I got errors, and now I need to use multidex for debugging.

My question is if the first library is redundant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: I am already using multidex, but when I try to debug in my device, the app is installed with a gray icon that says _App_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the next dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

It is not necessary to use the particular dependency for authentication with Google+

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
```

And finally, I don't need to use multidex when I add my dependencies exactly

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

I found [this information](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section **Selectively compiling APIs into your executable**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

did you syn files after adding dependencies in build.gradle i.e. a cream colored bar appearing on top saving Gradle files have changed since last project....click on that to syn your new dependencies....

Comment: Yes, I did that. I am just asking if the first dependency is necessary when I am using the second.