# Android studio - finished with non-zero exit value 1 exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added Fabric to my application from Android studio via Fabric plugin, after that I could not run my application. It shows following error while running the project.

Error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':qApp:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

build.gradle file after included Fabric:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':payPalDemo1')
    compile project(':uberLibrary')
    compile project(':bSLibrary')
    compile project(':pullToRefresh')
    compile project(':androidmapsutils')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/cardio.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/UserFormValidation.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

It was working fine before adding Fabric, how I can resolve this issue? please help me. I am running on Ubuntu Machine.

Comment: where are you running your app? I mean on which device

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `multiDexEnabled true` in your gradle file as below:

```
    defaultConfig {
...
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
...
}
```

After that `clean` and `rebuild` your project.

It's work for me.I hope its helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You app has crossed the dex limit of 65k methods so you need to enable multidex in your app.

add

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

to gradle and also add **multidex:true**

```
defaultConfig {

multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Also extend your application class with **MultiDexApplication**.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library) and [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

***note** - you might wanna remove playservices with more bifurcated version like  [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) link explains, to avoid multidex issues.