# Google analytical in android

Tags: android

Hello Everyone i am integrating google analytical in my android app.I got reference/help from androidhive
[I just got help from below link and all are perfecr][1]

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is caused by improper use of the multidexing library.
You should create your own application class and use it name in manifest and other places. You have to call `MultiDex.install(this)` inside it to use multidex

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

or extend MultiDexApplication by your custom Application class

[Read more about multidexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/1897374)

Comment: i am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: could you please tell me in detail

Comment: @jr.abhi you should to create application class as in your example, use it in your manifest and add method `@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }` to this class

Comment: kk Thanks I will try and let you know the result

Comment: Tahnks Now i'm not getting the problem of MultiDex

Comment: Now I will check google analytics if data is sending or not

Comment: Thanks @Kirill Shalnov

Comment: @jr.abhi you can apply this answer if it was useful =)