# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;

Tags: java, android, dex

### I am getting this error while I am trying to compile my project on android studio

```
app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

    `com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`
```

### Below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "paritosh.d9.groceries"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}
```

*Its been hours I am trying to solve this problem. I have tried to
remove my play services dependencies but this didn't solve the issue.
Please help me in solving this problem. Thanks*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplication in dependencies – two classes are the same. You should understand which lib contains that one you should exclude. In order to do this, you need to **run the next line in console:**

```
./gradlew app:androidDependencies
```

Also, you can do the same with **Gradle plugin in Android Studio:**

[image]

The output will be like this:

```
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- io.realm:realm-android-library:1.0.0
|    \--- com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
+--- com.android.support:design:23.3.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0
```

Look for the duplication of `gms` lib and exclude it like this:

```
 compile(group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-gcm', version: "8.4.0") {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement')
    }
```

If you still can't solve the problem, please, show me the output of

```
./gradlew app:androidDependencies
```

Comment: Hi Val...!!  Thank you for your assistance. I am now able to successfully compile my project. There was a version difference between two of the google services libraries. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Val hey i got very long output, i can't understand! Please help!

Comment: @Val i solved this problem but thank you for good detail description..
and i solved my problem by this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244653/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-auth-api-signin-internal-zzf