# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >

Tags: java, android, exception

When I execute my app I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

It happened suddenly and I don't know why
Here is the code of my gradle setting of the module that doesn't works:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.uniba.di.sms.studente.adem.bikesharing"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

and this is the code of the gradle setting of the full app

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

EDIT:
Error I get after enabling multidexing:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.rop.type.Type.internClassName(Type.java:415)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line, and rebuild

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'`

If until issue is not resolved then integrate multi dex lib, you can see [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Comment: I don't think that enabling multidexing the app will work because the app works on other members of my team's pc

Comment: Yes, i agree dear same problem i faced, and one more point after 5.1 android level app compile successfully, just you try you will get output

Comment: Now I have a new Error. I'm editing the question so you can see what happened

Comment: Delete your .gradle,a pp.iml and build folder and restart studio

Comment: and then what do i do?

Comment: Still same issue is there ?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing Google Play services "location" service twice. `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0` line itself contains location services. Therefore its redundant and cause above error.

You probably wanna remove this line,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

And keep this,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

Google has listed all the sub services which comes with Google Play Services. And you should not import `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0` complete library unless otherwise you uses all the services. [This link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) has complete sub list of Google Play services, so you can import only the necessary ones.