# Memory Leaks with Views android

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, custom-keyboard, android-input-method

I have created a custom keyboard app My Input service looks like this [Softkeyboard.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java) , My app is consuming high RAM around 150-200 MB,when I tried to dump memory info from

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo
```

this is what I get even when my keyboard is not opened.

```
Objects
                   Views:      364         ViewRootImpl:        1
             AppContexts:        3           Activities:        0
                  Assets:        5        AssetManagers:        5
           Local Binders:       45        Proxy Binders:       32
           Parcel memory:       16         Parcel count:       64
        Death Recipients:        4      OpenSSL Sockets:        0


Views:      364 //number increases when I open and close keyboard for few times.
```

My main methods from keyboard class :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public View onCreateInputView() {
    /*abc logo call back and volley request*/

 //   abcLogoManager.getInstance().abcLogoCallBack(this, this);
 //   abcLogoModel = new abcLogoModel();
  //  abcLogoManager.getInstance().getabcLogo();
    BaseActivity.printLog(TAG, "onCreateInputView invoked!");
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    isCapsOnOff = true;
    themevalue = appSession.getThemeValue();
    this.onChangeKeyBoardTheme();
    RelativeLayout abcKeyboardContainer;
    if (themevalue == 1) {
        abcKeyboardContainer = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_keyboard_container, null, false);
        if (isNumericKeyboard) {
            mInputView = (KeyboardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_numeric_light_gray, null, false);
        } else {
            mInputView = (KeyboardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, null, false);
        }
    } else {
        abcKeyboardContainer = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_keyboard_container_grey, null);
        if (isNumericKeyboard) {
            mInputView = (KeyboardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_numeric_drak_gray, null);
        } else {
            mInputView = (KeyboardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputgrey, null);
        }
    }
    abcKeyboardContainerLayout = (abcKeyboardContainerLayout) abcKeyboardContainer.findViewById(R.id.abcKeyboardContainerLayout);
    this.mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    this.mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

    if (getBeforeCursorText() != null && getBeforeCursorText().length() > 1 && doubleTapOnCaps.equals("")) {
        this.mInputView.setShifted(false);
        mQwertyKeyboard.setShiftOnOff(getResources(), mInputView.isShifted(), doubleTapOnCaps, themevalue);
    } else {
        doubleTapOnCaps = "";
        this.mInputView.setShifted(true);
        mQwertyKeyboard.setShiftOnOff(getResources(), mInputView.isShifted(), doubleTapOnCaps, themevalue);
    }
    tabsList = new ArrayList<>();
    tabsList.addAll(getDefaultTabs());

    ivLogoabc = (ImageView) abcKeyboardContainer.findViewById(R.id.ivLogoabc);
    /*view find from tabs hidden relative layout*/
    rlHiddenTabs = (RelativeLayout) abcKeyboardContainer.findViewById(R.id.rlHiddenTabs);
    ibFourDots = (ImageButton) rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.ibFourDots);
    textViewSuggestion1 = (abcTextView) rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.textViewSuggestion1);
    textViewSuggestion2 = (abcTextView) rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.textViewSuggestion2);
    textViewSuggestion3 = (abcTextView) rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.textViewSuggestion3);
    view1 = rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.view1);
    view2 = rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.view2);
    imageViewSmileyToKeyboard = (ImageView) rlHiddenTabs.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSmileyToKeyboard);


    /*view find from tabs shown realtive layout */
    rlShownTabs = (RelativeLayout) abcKeyboardContainer.findViewById((R.id.rlShownTabs));
    mImageViewKeyboard = (ImageButton) rlShownTabs.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonKeyboard);
    horizontalScrollView = (CenterLockHorizontalScrollview) rlShownTabs.findViewById(R.id.hscroll);
    LinearLayout lnrLytTabs = (LinearLayout) rlShownTabs.findViewById(R.id.keyboard_tab_layout);
    rlShownTabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    /*Click on Four Dots*/
    ibFourDots.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageViewSmileyToKeyboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    mImageViewKeyboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivLogoabc.setOnClickListener(this);


    for (int i = 0; i < tabsList.size(); i++) {
        RelativeLayout rlTabs = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rlTabs.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        int tabMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_10);
        TextView tvTab = new TextView(this);
        abcConstants.setTvFont(this, tvTab);
        tvTab.setAllCaps(true);
        tvTab.setTypeface(tvTab.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        tvTab.setTextSize(14);
        ImageView ivLogoSetting = new ImageView(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(rlTabs.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT, rlTabs.getLayoutParams().MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(tabMargin, 0, tabMargin, 0);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        tvTab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        if (themevalue == 1) {
            tvTab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            rlTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_popup));
        } else {
            tvTab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            rlTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_bgColor_grey_theme));
        }
        tvTab.setId(tabsList.get(i).getId());

        if (tabsList.get(i).getTabName().equals("SETTING")) {
            tvTab.setText("");
            if (themevalue == 1) {
                tvTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_addmoretab, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                tvTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_addmoretab_graytheme, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        } else {
            tvTab.setText(tabsList.get(i).getTabName());
        }
        tvTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvTab.setOnClickListener(this);

        rlTabs.addView(tvTab);
        rlTabs.addView(ivLogoSetting);
        tabsList.get(i).setTvTabs(tvTab);
        lnrLytTabs.addView(rlTabs);
    }
    abcKeyboardContainerLayout.addView(mInputView);
    xHeight = mInputView.getMeasuredHeight();

    return abcKeyboardContainer;
}

public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
    BaseActivity.printLog(TAG, "onCreateCandidatesView invoked! ");
    this.mCandidateView = new CandidateView(this);
    this.mCandidateView.setService(this);
    return this.mCandidateView;
}

@Override
public void onFinishInputView(boolean finishingInput) {
    BaseActivity.printLog(TAG, "onFinishInputView invoked! ");
    String isFromMain = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("MAINACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
    super.onFinishInputView(finishingInput);
    if (mConnector != null) {
        mConnector.onDialogDismiss("onFinishInputView");
    }
    if(appSession.getIsUserVisitToMainActivity())
    {
        BaseActivity.printLog(TAG , "Process got killed from on finish Input view");
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

    }
}


@Override
public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    BaseActivity.printLog(TAG, "onStartInput invoked!");
    super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

    mInputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
    this.mComposing.setLength(0);
    this.updateCandidates();
    // GPSTracker.getInstance(this);
    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    //google analytics // for testing
   /* abcApplication mabcApplication = (abcApplication)getApplication();
    Tracker mTracker = mabcApplication.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.setScreenName("Image~ " + getResources().getString(R.string.app_screen_name_keyboard_start));
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());*/

    if (attribute.hintText != null) {
        strHintText = String.valueOf(attribute.hintText);
    } else {
        strHintText = "";
    }

    if (!restarting) {
        this.mMetaState = 0;
    }
    this.mPredictionOn = false;
    this.mCompletionOn = false;
    this.mCompletions = null;
    switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:        // 2
            this.mCurKeyboard = this.mNumericKeyboard;
            this.isNumericKeyboard = true;
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:    // 4
            this.mCurKeyboard = this.mSymbolsKeyboard;
            this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:        // 3
            this.mCurKeyboard = this.mNumericKeyboard;
            this.isNumericKeyboard = true;
            break;

        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:        // 1
            this.mCurKeyboard = this.mQwertyKeyboard;
            this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
            this.mPredictionOn = true;

            int variation = attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION;
            if (variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD || variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                this.mPredictionOn = false;
            }
            //||variation==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
            if (variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS || variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI || variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER) {
                this.mPredictionOn = false;
            }

            if ((attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE) != 0) {
                this.mPredictionOn = false;
                this.mCompletionOn = this.isFullscreenMode();
            }
            updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
            break;
        default:
            this.mCurKeyboard = this.mQwertyKeyboard;
            this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
            this.updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
            break;
    }
    if (mCurKeyboard != null) {
        this.mCurKeyboard.setImeOptions(getResources(), attribute.imeOptions, themevalue);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    if (attribute != null) {
        try {
            inputType = attribute.inputType;
            switch (attribute.inputType) {
                case 33: // Text_email Type
                    this.mInputView.setShifted(false);
                    this.mQwertyKeyboard.setShiftOnOff(getResources(), mInputView.isShifted(), doubleTapOnCaps, themevalue);
                    this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
                    break;
                case 129:  // Text_password Type
                    this.mInputView.setShifted(false);
                    this.mQwertyKeyboard.setShiftOnOff(getResources(), mInputView.isShifted(), doubleTapOnCaps, themevalue);
                    this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
                    break;
                case 145: // Text_password_visible Type
                    this.mInputView.setShifted(false);
                    this.mQwertyKeyboard.setShiftOnOff(getResources(), mInputView.isShifted(), doubleTapOnCaps, themevalue);
                    this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
                    break;
                case 225: // Text_password_web Type
                    this.mInputView.setShifted(false);
                    this.mQwertyKeyboard.setShiftOnOff(getResources(), mInputView.isShifted(), doubleTapOnCaps, themevalue);
                    this.isNumericKeyboard = false;
                    break;
                case 18: // Number_password Type
                    this.mCurKeyboard = this.mNumericKeyboard;
                    this.isNumericKeyboard = true;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How to clear these views? I tried keep null to all view when keyboard is hidden but that is not working!!

I tried calling

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

it drops the memory consumption directly to 10 MB and clear all the views but in this case , my keyboard open very slowly.

Here is lifecyle,every time when I open keyboard (when I kill process on onFinishInputview) :

```
 I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9256
 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
 I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
 I/MultiDex: install
 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
 D/SoftKeyboard: onCreate invoked! 

 D/SoftKeyboard: onInitializeInterface invoked! 
 D/SoftKeyboard: onStartInput invoked!
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code. You have to fix the memory leak itself,  not find some workaround.

Comment: @Nibha Jain DId Application class not help you?

Comment: @XaverKapeller : edited

Comment: @Nisarg : what should be there on Application class?

Comment: @NibhaJain From logcat error I can say,you should enable multi dex support, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/3117966) out for [info](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Comment: I did it already @Nisarg

Comment: @NibhaJain Okay,Can you post your build.gradle ?