# .dex file exceeds 64k methods during signing

Tags: android, dex

I've just finished working on my android app and I run it in android studio emulator. It's fine and everything works well, but I have an issue - when I want to generate signed apk , I got these two errors and  can't complete apk building process. 
I've tried a lot of things to solve these two errors that i got,  but no result.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoDUf.jpg)

Comment: Enable multidex, check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/3796083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the 64K method limit.

Check if you've added unnecessary dependencies, check your ProGuard configuration.

Follow the instructions from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: after i did these steps , i got more than 2 errors and they are deferent than what i got before ,....

Comment: after i did these steps , i got more than 2 errors and they are different than what i got before , https://www.photobox.co.uk/slideshow?album_id=4730712146

Answer (score 1):

Enable multiDex, do that in your `build.gradle` file, in `defaultConfig` block

And if your `minSdkVersion < 21` then also add `multidex support library` in your `dependencies` block

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        multiDexEnabled true // add this line

    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
   ...

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' //If minSdkVersion < 21

}
```

Comment: we don't know if OP is running `minSdkVersion >= 21`

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov Please explain more, this has always fixed the issue for me, even if my `minSdkVersion was < 21`

Comment: By the time of my comment you didn't include `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`