# Error while moving android project from eclipse to Android studio

Tags: android, spring, eclipse, android-studio

I am moving my project from eclipse to android studio.when I run my project I get the following error.

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>
> Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

In my **Build.gradle** I have added the following dependencies.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.buildteam"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.6.jar')

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

}
```

I have tried so many questions from stack overflow. But I couldn't find a solution. 
Please help me.

Comment: how did you open your project in android studio? import or open?

Comment: Imported as eclipse project

Comment: Refer this link
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please do the following:

Update android studio to lastes
Update android sdk and adt to latest
Ideally use **minSdkVersion (lowest possible) <= targetSdkVersion == compileSdkVersion (latest SDK)**
Please make the changes in build.gradle
Wait for gradle to sync
Run the application

After trying out the above steps, if we fail, please checkout the all changes made during the conversion of the project and convert the eclipse project to android studio project using android studio.

Comment: I have tried it. But still I have the same error. I have tried converting the eclipse project to android studio project using android studio too.

Comment: Please make a sample project in eclipse and convert the project to android studio project using android studio. If you do not experience any problem in building, then the problem is in the dependencies of your project. Can you please do that?