# Why i Got this Exception just in Android 4.4 (checkRenderContextUnsafe)

Tags: android

I saw this exception in **Firebase Crash Report**. but i didnt know why its happened. and it is happened just in **android 4.4.**
does any one know why I got  this exception?

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
    android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.checkRenderContextUnsafe (HardwareRenderer.java:1791)
    android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw (HardwareRenderer.java:1474)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:2839)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2705)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2274)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1311)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6711)
    android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:813)
    android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:613)
    android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:583)
    android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:799)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5756)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: this is most certainly not a dupe of that ^

Comment: @RatilalChopda i know what is NullPointerException! please read question carefully

Answer (score 1):

I've same NPE on KitKat after upgrading support library to 26.1.0.
I think the reason is in FragmentManager changes.

```
    @Override
    @CallSuper
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // If we're attached to a window, assume we're in the normal performTraversals
        // drawing path for Animations running. It's not safe to change the layer type
        // during drawing, so post it to the View to run later. If we're not attached
        // or we're running on N and above, post it to the view. If we're not on N and
        // not attached, do it right now since existing platform versions don't run the
        // hwui renderer for detached views off the UI thread making changing layer type
        // safe, but posting may not be.
        // Prior to N posting to a detached view from a non-Looper thread could cause
        // leaks, since the thread-local run queue on a non-Looper thread would never
        // be flushed.
        if (ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow(mView) || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            mView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
                }
            });
        } else {
            mView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        }
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
    }
```

EDIT: More info. It happens only if you have custom animations for fragment transactions in your app. After making transaction and starting activity this crash happens

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use the new **Multidex** support library
[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734)

Comment: perhaps you want to explain why you think this will solve the issue