# How to fixed error converting bytecode to dex Cause:com.android.dex.DexException:Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier?

Tags: java, android, gradle

**I updated android studio and build tools.**

I got some error like this:

*Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier;*

```
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDevelopmentDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier;

Comment: have you google your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture
, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Seems like this is a different problem.  Certainly the error message is different.

Comment: i already  added multiDexEnabled = true  in my app gradle file

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/4797289