# Universal Image Loader Library error with android studio on android 5.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, universal-image-loader

Universal Image Loader Library thought this crash while initializing in android studio on huawei device with android os version 5.0.1

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.q8car.andriod.activity-2/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

my gradle file is as following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.mutualmobile.gradle.plugins:dexinfo:0.1.2'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        multiDexEnabled = true
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libblasV8.so'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // modules
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android')
    // sdks
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

Comment: Did you try rebuilding? Did proguard enabled?

Comment: yes I clean and build many times and still have the same problem, how to enable proguard ?

Comment: In build.gradle. Did `minifyEnabled` = true or false?

Comment: can you add gradle file , have you enabled multidex ?

Comment: @nhoxbypass it is false

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez kindly check my edit

Comment: Which version of android-studio you're using, is that issue happened only on this device?, or you mean it's thrown when you try to compile project.

Comment: @Ibrahim Android 3.0

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail Ok,  use `implementation` instead of `compile`, then try to add `multiDex` to your app following way https://stackoverflow.com/a/36952875/6490462, Also provide your `ffmpeg4android` dependencies, it's contain jar files ?, do you have *build.gradle* for **project** ?  because `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` should be `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`, plus adding `google()` to `repositories {
  
        }`

Comment: @Ibrahim I have solved it by download library zip file and include it as module in my project , also I am not facing any problem now when I disable instant run in android studio

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail you should post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add:

```
depenencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   ...
}
```

Comment: still have the same problem, it is working on all devices just not work on huwawi with android os 5.0.1

Comment: have tried to test it with deleting             abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"

Comment: I have commented it and still have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by download library zip file and include it as module in my project , also I am not facing any problem now when I disable instant run in android studio