# REST Android Client using Spring and OAuth2 Error DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

I have a server running and I want to connect an android client to the server with spring's oauth2. I use Android Studio. My problem is related to the gradle configurations, which I don't know how it should be.

**Problem**: When I run the app, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I have seen many other questions with the same problem, I tried the solutions (like adding `multiDexEnabled true`, clean and rebuild the project etc.) but none of them worked. I think that the problem is caused because these two dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.0.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
```

might have some common jars or something. Any help would be appreciated.

---

My build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "readinghood.restclient"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

My build.gradle (Project: RestClient)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you instantiated Multidex Application ?

Comment: @ADM What exactly do you mean? What part of the code should I change?

Comment: If multidex is the problem Then follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library) . Get back if not worked.

Comment: I have tried all solutions suggested but nothing works. I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Multidex .installl()` in application class and added Application class to manifest ?  And try Clean Project and the Rebuild Project.

Comment: The problem is I don't have an Application class. But I did add the `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in my manifest file. I only have an Activity class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165977/discussion-between-thanasis-and-adm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. There were two modules that were duplicate, so I had to exclude them from the Module build.gradle file. What I had to do was:

```
compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3') {
    exclude module: 'spring-android-core'
}

compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.0.RC1'){
    exclude module: 'spring-web'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

android {

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
packagingOptions
        {
            exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-IN F/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        }
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    applicationId "com.support.project"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

}

Try this it should work for your cause. [Go through this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to understand why we should add this line of code **multiDexEnabled true**

Comment: Thank you for replying. I replaced in my build.gradle file the part of the `android{}` with your code but I have the same problem. `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

Comment: Please check this dependency, may be conflicting with each other                    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'

Comment: Yes that is the problem but I dont know how to solve it