# Multidex Could not find class

Tags: android, android-multidex

As I have reached the 64K Methods limit I have activated Multidex in my app.

I'm testing on 2 different devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S7 (API 24)
- Alps A733 (API 19, Google Services not up to date)

Everything works find on the first one but on the second one I get these errors and the entire app freeze (doesn't crash).

**Errors**

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfr.zzazv
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfr.zzs
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

I followed [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.htm) so:

In my gradle I have added:

- `multiDexEnabled true`
- `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` as I'm targetting API 16 as minSDKVersion

In my custom Application class

```
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
```

To try to fix the issue I've created a `multidex-config.txt` file that is in the same folder as the build.gradle where it is referenced.

**multidex-config.txt (EDITED)**

```
android/app/job/JobScheduler.class
android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.class
android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.class
```

then in the gradle:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        //...
    }

    debugStaging {
        initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        //...
    }

    release {
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        minifyEnabled false
        //...
    }
}
```

I think I've missed something. Any clue?

### EDIT

**Gradle file**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        //...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 10
        //...
    }

    buildTypes {
        //...
        debug {
            //...
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        }

        debugStaging {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            //...
        }

        release {
            //...
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //...
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 6
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        jumboMode true
    }
    //...
}

ext {
    //...
}

dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
   //...
}

// Required by Firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle file? Where is multiDexEnabled written?

Comment: what is your minsdk version?

Comment: additionally you need to add MultiDexApplication class inside manifest file.

Comment: @ArnabKar I've added the entire gradle (minus irrelevant/condidential data).

Comment: @Radhey As mentioned my min SDK is 16. There are 3 ways to add Multidex for the Application: via the Manifest, by extenting the `MultiDexApplication` class or by adding `MultiDex.install(this);`. I chose the last option

Comment: set it 14 and let me know.

Comment: @Radhey I can't as my app is using features not available in API below 16

Comment: Did you try removing the -keep as given in my answer below? I believe thats the fix actually.

Comment: ASAIK if you want multidex enable, min sdk should be 14.

Comment: @Radhey why should it be 14?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724082/1848157\

Comment: No it shouldn't. Min SDK is independant from Multidex. You only need to provide different things depending on the min version you target (e.g. you need to add extra conf if you target API below 20)

Answer (score 1):

The format of the multidex-config.txt seems different from the one described in [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

> It seems like the **-keep** should not be here. Its part of
>   **multiDexKeepProguard** not **multiDexKeepFile**

The format should be

```
com/example/MyClass.class
com/example/MyOtherClass.class
```

Since the Alps A733 is having **API 19**, (any app having API level less than 20),  your app crashes with the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.`

Comment: Yeah you're right. I mixed the format for multiDexKeepFile and multiDexKeepProguard. So have changed it but still get the error (I'm gonna update my question with the new implementation)

Comment: Is it the same format to keep classes from a library as to keep your own classes?

Comment: Yes, its exactly the same