# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, runtimeexception

#### When i trying to run my project this error showing

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.kishankalola.earnbyspin, PID: 11122
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kishankalola.earnbyspin-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kishankalola.earnbyspin-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6054)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5611)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5550)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1628)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6328)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:937)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kishankalola.earnbyspin-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kishankalola.earnbyspin-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6039)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5611) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5550) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1628) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6328) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1076) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:937)

## app level gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kishankalola.earnbyspin"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
} 
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## project level gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## Android Menifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kishankalola.earnbyspin">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SetupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ForgotePassword" />

    <activity android:name=".RedeemActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PaypalActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PaytmActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Try to enable multidex support. As done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library