# after adding glide 4.8.0 dependency gradle build with error Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData;

Tags: android

Project sync with success but when i try to build project i get multidex error.
I don't know if there is conflict with the glide library and android library.
Please for a solution

gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'

compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
compile 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.XunMengWinter:CircularAnim:0.3.4'
compile 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.8'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'me.jahirfiquitiva:FABsMenu:1.1.1'

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

}
```

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/5148289

Comment: thanks but nothing seems to work there

Answer (score 0):

Try adding annotationProcess as well, and see if that works.
Add the code given below in the same file (gradle):

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```