# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Android 9 (Pie)

Tags: android

I have following error in **Android 9 (Pie)** I don't get where is  the error I think its related to **google gms libs**.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at fa.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):3)
  at ez.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):3)
  at fb.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):15)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.al.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):6)
  at ee.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):21)
  at ee.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ac.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@14574081@14.5.74 (100400-219897028):4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: it looks related to obfuscation, have you tried to disable `minifiedEnabled` ?

Comment: this is multidexing issue, have you enabled multidex in your app?

Comment: @shizhen `minifiedEnabled = false`

Comment: @KaranMer Yes multidex already enabled.

Comment: have you added dependency `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`

Comment: have you tried remove google gms pulgin then sync and then add it again ?

Comment: also if you are extending from `Application` class extend it from `MultiDexApplication`

Comment: @KaranMer I do every things that related to multidex according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/9868485

Comment: if you have done everything, then try to clean and build or invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @KaranMer I have already clean ,build ,invalidate cache and restart , app run perfectly all other devices instead of android 9 . I got this error only on android 9

Comment: add `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" 
           android:required="false"/>` to your manifest application tag

Comment: @KaranMer can u explain this user-library tag ??

Comment: @code4rox : they have deprecated support for Apache HTTP client starting from andorid pie, check change log for reference https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is official docs**

> If you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 or
>   below and your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above,
>   you must include the following declaration within the 
>   element of AndroidManifest.xml.

```
  <uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

> This is handled for you if you are using
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0 and is not necessary
>   if your app is targeting a lower API level.

**and also add this tag in Menifest.xml**

```
<application
.....
.....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

if you are using send and received request to server like (Volley , retrofit and Http request)

**Also try this one (optional)**

convert the project to `AndroidX` make sure backup of project first.

Comment: Proper fix for me!