# ClassNotFoundException BaseDexClass.Loader.findClass

Tags: java, android, android-layout, google-play-services, google-console-developer

classnotfoundexception basedexclassloader Showing my Google console App Crash report but i'm unable to find but App running perfect from android Studio but when i try to download from play store first time app crash then start working fine
[Crash Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwZh2.png)

Comment: I think you must enable multidex, check this link to enable multidex in your application; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: i have one Question as you mention very helpful link written                                                       public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

}   we have to inherit all the class with MultiDexApplication or just Main Activity class

Comment: No, not in all Activity, it just in YouApplication  class