# Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/Request$Method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

i'm trying to make a about us page by following a youtube tutorial, i have added a library **implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.1.1'** 
in dependencies and after sync it is not giving me any error. But when i try to run project it's giving an error
Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/Request$Method
i've used volley previously in this same project but i don't get why it's giving this error

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.1.1'

}
```

[image]

Comment: You should enable multidexing to solve your issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: usually can be solved by cleaning the project and doing a fresh sync/build