# Is there a way to increase Android DEX 64k limit?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting an error while adding new libraries as Android dependencies. The limit of 64k is too low for me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Answer (score 1):

YES,

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        **multiDexEnabled true**
    }
```

dependencies {

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

}

Please do changes in your build.gradle file