# Add External Jar file in cordova 3.4.0 application

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am creating two custom plugins for android use this plugin described in my plugin.xml. My plugin.xml file like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="com.my.mybiometric"
    version="1.2">

    <name>myBiometric</name>
    <description>myBiometric Plugin</description>
    <license>Apache 2.0</license>
    <keywords>media,upload</keywords>

<engines>
    <engine name="cordova-android" version=">=3.4.0" />
</engines>
    <js-module src="www/js/Media2.js" name="Media2">
        <clobbers target="mediaRec.startRecord" /> 
    </js-module>
    <js-module src="www/js/VoiceUpload.js" name="VoiceUpload">
         <clobbers target="VoiceUpload" />
    </js-module>

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
         <feature name="Media2">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.my.mybiometric.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="VoiceUpload">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.my.mybiometric.UploadHandler"/>
    </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.mybiometric.myBiometric"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
          </activity>
    </config-file>

        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/AudioHandler.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />
        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/UploadHandler.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />
        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/AppLog.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />
        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/MyResponseHandler.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />
        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/Recorder.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />

        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/VoiceBiometricClient.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />
        <source-file src="platforms/android/src/com/my/plugins/VoiceBiometricClientUsage.java" target-dir="src/com/my/mybiometric" />

     </platform>
</plugin>
```

after build and run the project the media2 plugin is working fine but when i call the voiceupload plugin its return the "**class not found**" error for voice upload i am using "android-async-http-1.4.4.jar". I add the jar file into libs folder i added manually.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: @Sid I can't print the logs. I dont have a permission to connect the device to system in my office

Comment: @Sid did u know where i put the external jar file cordova projects

Comment: @Sid But I create this project via command line using node.js.how to d o that?

Answer (score 4):

1. You put your jar file in your plugin in the folder platforms/android/src/libs
2. In plugin.xml you add the line

   `<source-file src="platforms/android/src/libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar" target-dir="libs" />`
3. no 3.

Comment: Does this actually work?  I get an error because cordova looks from my jar in the plugins directory even though I specified a path in the directory folder.

Comment: are you installing your plugin using the cli/plugman or are you working directly in a java project in eclipse of android studio ?

Comment: I was just using the cli cordova plugin add /path/to/plugin.  I was getting  an error: Could not find my-library.jar because it was looking for the jar in the plugins directory rather than the platforms directory.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfect for me but I put the JAR into `platforms/android/libs` instead. And, of course, changing to this path as `src` in `<source file... />`.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896990/noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse/21898031#21898031)

You need to go to Go to Project->Properties and make some changes as per the answer.

Hope this helps.