# Sorry- The application (app_name) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, authorize.net

Hello friends i am developing an app where i had to integrate Authorize.net , i successfully integrate it but when running application em getting error Like => Sorry- The application (app_name) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again . Could you please review it thank you

Source :-http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/

main.xml =>

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=
     "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/main" />
```

=> Example.Activity

```
package net.authorize;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import net.authorize.android.AuthNet;
import net.authorize.android.AuthNetActivityBase;
import net.authorize.android.SimpleActivity;
import net.authorize.android.button.AuthNetButton;
import net.authorize.data.Address;
import net.authorize.data.Customer;
import net.authorize.data.EmailReceipt;
import net.authorize.data.Order;
import net.authorize.data.ShippingCharges;
import net.authorize.data.creditcard.CreditCard;
import net.authorize.xml.MessageType;
import net.authorize.xml.Result;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ExampleActiviy extends SimpleActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load merchant info
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        authNetObj = AuthNet.getInstance(Environment.SANDBOX,
            R.layout.authnet_credentials_dialog, R.id.authnet_loginid_edit,
            R.id.authnet_password_edit, R.id.authnet_auth_cancel_button,
            R.id.authnet_auth_login_button);

        // prepare the authCapture button
        AuthNetButton authCaptureButton = authNetObj.getButton(this,
            "Authorize and Capture");
        authCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                launchAuthCaptureIntent();
            }
        });

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        layout.addView(authCaptureButton);
    }

    /**
     * Activity launcher for authCapture transactions.
     */
    private void launchAuthCaptureIntent() {
        String refId = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        BigDecimal totalAmount = new BigDecimal(19.99);

        /*
         * listing these out only to show the required
         * 'parameter set' that should be passed into
         * the create Intent method.
         */
        CreditCard creditCard = CreditCard.createCreditCard();
        creditCard.setCreditCardNumber("4111111111111111");
        Calendar expCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        expCal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);
        creditCard.setExpirationDate(expCal.getTime());

        Order order = Order.createOrder();
        order.setTotalAmount(new BigDecimal(19.95));
        order.setDescription("Android Test Order");

        Customer customer = null;
        Address shippingAddress = null;
        ShippingCharges shippingCharges = null;
        EmailReceipt emailReceipt = null;
        HashMap<String, String> merchantDefinedFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
        merchantDefinedFields.put("notes", "sent from SampleActivity");

        Intent authNetIntent = authNetObj.createAIMAuthCaptureIntent(this, refId,totalAmount,
            creditCard, order, customer, shippingAddress,shippingCharges, emailReceipt,
            merchantDefinedFields);
        /*
         * final launch command to spawn the Activity and provide a
         * callback where the result data can be processed
         */
        authNetIntent.putExtra(
          AuthNetActivityBase.EXTRA_DUPLICATE_TXN_WINDOW_SECS,
          5);
        launchSubActivity(authNetIntent,
         createPaymentIntentResultCallback());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a payment Intent ResultCallback.
     *
     * @return ResultCallback
     */
    private ResultCallback createPaymentIntentResultCallback() {
        return new SimpleActivity.ResultCallback() {

            public void resultTransactionCanceled(Enum<?> txnType) {
                showAlert((TransactionType) txnType + " canceled",
                "");
            }

            public void resultTransactionFailed(Enum<?> txnType,
                Result result) {

                MessageType msgType = MessageType.E00000;
                StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder(msgType.getValue())
                    .append(": ").append(msgType.getText());

                net.authorize.aim.Result aimResult = (net.authorize.aim.Result) result;

                errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                if (aimResult.getTransactionResponseErrors().size() > 0) {
                    for (ResponseReasonCode respReasonCode : aimResult
                        .getTransactionResponseErrors()) {
                        errorBuilder.append(respReasonCode.getResponseReasonCode())
                            .append(": ").append(respReasonCode.getReasonText()).append("\n");
                    }
                } else if (aimResult.getMessages().size() > 0) {
                    for (MessageType msgType1 :
                aimResult.getMessages()) {
                        errorBuilder.append(msgType1.getValue()).append(": ")
                            .append(msgType1.getText()).append("\n");
                    }
                }
                showAlert((TransactionType) txnType + " failed",
                    errorBuilder.toString());
            }

            public void resultTransactionSucceeded(Enum<?> txnType, Result result) {

                net.authorize.aim.Result aimResult = (net.authorize.aim.Result) result;
                showAlert((TransactionType) txnType + " success",
                    "authCode: " + aimResult.getAuthCode() + "\n" + "refTransId: " +
                    aimResult.getTransId());
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Create a simple alert dialog.
     *
     * @param title
     * @param message
     */
    private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        // Show an error to the user
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.authorize"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- ** Security Activities - REQUIRED ** -->
 <activity android:name=
    "net.authorize.android.security.MobileMerchantAuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
 <activity android:name=
"net.authorize.android.security.LoginBaseActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
 <!-- AIM Activity -->
 <activity android:name=
"net.authorize.android.aim.AuthCaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity
            android:name="net.authorize.ExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat =>

```
04-22 14:58:17.999: D/AndroidRuntime(480): Shutting down VM
04-22 14:58:17.999: W/dalvikvm(480): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.authorize/net.authorize.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.authorize.ExampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.authorize-1.apk]
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.authorize.ExampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.authorize-1.apk]
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-22 14:58:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  ... 11 more
04-22 14:58:44.428: D/AndroidRuntime(503): Shutting down VM
04-22 14:58:44.428: W/dalvikvm(503): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.authorize/net.authorize.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.authorize.ExampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.authorize-2.apk]
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.authorize.ExampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.authorize-2.apk]
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-22 14:58:44.458: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  ... 11 more
04-22 14:59:24.908: I/Process(503): Sending signal. PID: 503 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post your full logcat error.

Comment: Have you added any external jar file in your project?

Comment: Yes as per documentation provided by Authorize.net

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896990/noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse/21898031#21898031)

You need to go to Go to Project->Properties and make some changes as given in the answer.

Comment: Not Working at all :(

Comment: This should work bro..Are you following the correct steps as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: May i mail you my project