# NoClassDefFound Error in android after updating the SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I was using  ADT with Eclipse 22.3 version where my code was working fine but as soon  as I started using the latest version 22.6 (to implement few functions which could not be done in 22.3) i got this error. I tried out stuff like restart eclipse,clean project,build pathh also created libs folder and copied all jars in it.The class for which i am getting this error is a third party (AmazonS3Client).I have included all jars correctly checked them in referenced libraries.It was working well in earlier version but not here.please someone help

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export** and ensure `Android Private Libraries` are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using. Clean all projects  and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Go to Project->Properties and make some changes as per the answer.

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896990/noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse/21898031#21898031)