# ADT 22 ClassNotFoundException for Application class

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have problems generating a signed apk after upgrading to ADT 22. 
Every time that I generate a signed apk, it start with "ClassNotFoundException" on class that extends Application.
The only thing that I can do to make it works it's to do a "clean all" on Eclipse EVERY time that I have to generate the apk.
This is VERY annoying because if I forget to do it, the generated apk is corrupted!

P.S.
I have "Android Private Libraries" checked on "Order and Export" tab.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any external jar file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using android-support, gson and joda-time. I'm using external library project too, from my workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896990/noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse/21898031#21898031)

You need to go to Go to Project->Properties and make changes as per the answer.