# NoClassDefFoundError Exception Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been trying to use Sendgrid in my android application. It's a project I'm working on with 3 others. The application works just fine on their phones and emulators, but it always seems to crash on my emulator and phone with this error message

```
05-07 03:15:12.940: W/EGL_emulation(1336): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-07 03:15:13.510: D/onDestroy(1336): 2014-05-07 03:15:11
05-07 03:15:13.700: D/dalvikvm(1336): GC_CONCURRENT freed 338K, 33% free 3276K/4820K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 65ms
05-07 03:15:13.790: E/dalvikvm(1336): Could not find class 'com.github.sendgrid.SendGrid', referenced from method edu.upenn.capsproject.SurveyActivity$SendEmailWithSendGrid.doInBackground
05-07 03:15:13.790: W/dalvikvm(1336): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 744 (Lcom/github/sendgrid/SendGrid;) in Ledu/upenn/capsproject/SurveyActivity$SendEmailWithSendGrid;
05-07 03:15:13.790: D/dalvikvm(1336): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
05-07 03:15:13.790: D/dalvikvm(1336): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1505 at 0x07 in Ledu/upenn/capsproject/SurveyActivity$SendEmailWithSendGrid;.doInBackground
05-07 03:15:13.800: W/dalvikvm(1336): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.sendgrid.SendGrid
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at edu.upenn.capsproject.SurveyActivity$SendEmailWithSendGrid.doInBackground(SurveyActivity.java:368)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at edu.upenn.capsproject.SurveyActivity$SendEmailWithSendGrid.doInBackground(SurveyActivity.java:1)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-07 03:15:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     ... 4 more
05-07 03:15:15.219: W/EGL_emulation(1336): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-07 03:15:16.289: I/Process(1336): Sending signal. PID: 1336 SIG: 9
05-07 03:15:16.750: E/Trace(1362): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

I have the sendgrid-0.2.0-jar.jar.zip file in the referenced libraries path.

Comment: Have look at this [Use external jar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Comment: I tried most of those already. Unfortunately the top voted answers did not work.

Comment: Possible dulicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it. Mark all checkboxes and Click on Apply and clean the project.

Copied from my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898031/3204827) post

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't fix it unfortunately.