# NoClassDefFound error in referenced library project when updated to ADT 22

Tags: android, adt, noclassdeffounderror

I created an Android project using ADT 22. This project refers to a library project which has some jar files in 'libs' folder. Now the project I created giving 'NoClassDefFound' error. This problem is there only if I create project using ADT 22, I have couple of projects which I created earlier and this library project works perfectly fine with them.

**P.S. - I have ensured that 'Android Private Library' is checked in Java Build Path -> Order and Export** **and folder containing jars is 'libs' not 'lib'.**

I have already wasted lot of time finding its solution, somebody kindly help me with this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me creating a new workspace in eclipse solved this problem.

Comment: Tried! Still the same. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it. Mark all checkboxes and Click on Apply and clean the project.

Copied from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896990/noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse/21898031#21898031)