# I am trying to build a sample App from a Third Party SDK. I am getting a class not found exception and I am not able to figure out why?

Tags: java, android

Below is my logcat :

```
06-26 21:31:41.352: D/AndroidRuntime(9911): Shutting down VM
06-26 21:31:41.352: W/dalvikvm(9911): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4114b930)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.counterpath.sdkdemo.audiocall.PhoneApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.counterpath.sdkdemo.audiocall.PhoneApp" on path: /data/app/com.counterpath.sdkdemo.audiocall-1.apk
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.counterpath.sdkdemo.audiocall.PhoneApp" on path: /data/app/com.counterpath.sdkdemo.audiocall-1.apk
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
06-26 21:31:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(9911):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898031/1785412

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this did not help. Still getting the same exceptions.