# NoClassDefFoundError when running PopupMenu using android-support-v7-appcompat library in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-support-library

I am trying to implement a popup menu in my android application which is to be supported from android 2.2 . So i used the android-support-v7-appcompat support library to do it. But unfortunately i am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception. Can't able to sort it out , so can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

The logcat shows,

```
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.<init>(PopupMenu.java:66)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at com.example.basic.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:401)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-27 15:40:30.160: E/AndroidRuntime(26985):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898031/1785412

Comment: @SiddharthVyas Unfortunately your answer doesn't have anything to do with this issue. I wish someone would fix this ASAP.

Comment: You might wanna have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder?s=1|3.0891

Answer (score 0):

check out project -> properties -> Java Build Path/Order and Export. check the library and dependencies with android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder