# Implementing PopupMenu using appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, popupmenu

I have used `appcompat-v7` for implenting `popupmenu` in `listView items` my app is working fine on most of the devices but some of them particularly `SAMSUNG-SM-G730A with android 4.2.2` throws below mentioned error at runtime

```
       import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu

       PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
       popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());
```

Error Log

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
    at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(SourceFile:67)
    at bby.a(SourceFile:270)
    at bby.a(SourceFile:268)
    at bcd.onClick(SourceFile:253)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4437)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18365)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5285)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=248142

Comment: please, let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder)