# android studio is not builiding project for samsung 4.2.2

Tags: android

I have originally created my large project using Eclipse after android studio stable version came i migrated AS(Android studio).Currently Android studio is building for android 5.1 Nexus Tab 10 as well as 7 .but getting error after running on only samsung android 4.2.2.

[appcompat-v7 v21.0.0 causing crash on Samsung devices with Android v4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657348/appcompat-v7-v21-0-0-causing-crash-on-samsung-devices-with-android-v4-2-2)

i have tried above solution but problem is i don't have default proguard file as i have migrated from AS TO Eclipse .AS didn't generete proguard file.

then i did some research and created an app in eclipse and imported into Android Studio and it worked without using proguard .so my question what is happing AS is having problem or Samsung 4.2.2 with AppCompact. i got following error for samsung 4.2.2.plz guide me .thanks in advance

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:297)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
>               at com.generaldevelopers.smartserve.activities.MainActicity.onCreate(MainActicity.java:41)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: If it is not building then what are you launching to get the crash?

Comment: well does it compile for anything else than samsung?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski   I mean, the build that can successfully run app . i am getting above crash for that build ,sorry for my english

Comment: @BojanKseneman  yaa its compiling on Nexus 10 ,& 7. i am to compile for samsung 4.2.2 using eclipse but not with Android studio

Comment: Yet another Samsung related issue. You should see our crash log server. Samsung, Samsung, Samsung, Samsung, ... for about 50 times, then there was Huawei p7 once and nothing else. So much about good software on samsungs.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this by just

1. Adding  appcompat v7 as a library project to Android Studio.
2. Adding this line: `configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }`  to my app Gradle after depedency section.
3. Adding  `MultiDex.install(this);` in my Application class to resolve multidex issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here could be one the following

1. Your **sdk** might not have **appcompact_v7** library installed if not try installing it by opening **sdk manager**.
2. You are using older version of compact and your project requires new version.
3. You have not mentioned **appcompact_v7** correctly in your project **Gradle** file.

> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+
> }
> ```

specify appcompact_v7 path like this in your Gradle file

Try installing the latest **appcompact V7** library and cleaning your project.

Comment: i have provided like this compile                             'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'                                                      i have appcompact library installed in sdk the latest one  .i am using 22.1.1 as mentioned above and i have mentioned correctly . i am able to run on other devices apart from samsung 4.2.2