# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When i click on the application to lunch, it crashes out with this exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1038)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1102)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1399)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:126)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have studied this link [appcompat-v7 v21.0.0 causing crash on Samsung devices with Android v4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26657348/3819810) very similarl to my problem. but can't make it.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to fix this:
Add the following lines to the proguard file:

```
-keep class * extends android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
-keep class * implements android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
```

Then, refresh the build in your IDE, and build the APK again.

"Why is this happening?"
Well, `NoClassDefFoundErrors` happen when a class went missing at runtime, but was compiled.

I hope I helped you!

Comment: You forgot to mention that the dev did nothing wrong and samsung is the one at fault here.