# Android Activity turns White

Tags: android, screen, native, android-appcompat

Getting bug on touch mate tab TM-MID794C in which the activity turns out white but the button underneath still work fine. Clicking on right position on the button switch to the next Activity Which is not White (new opened activity is fine). But going back to previous activity it is still white. Using AppCompact library.

Comment: Show your xml and code?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926995/activity-wont-render-randomly-shows-only-white-screen-on-samsung

Comment: @Qasim he has answered to this post already. Even tho its wrong, as he has not helped, just commented. 

Muhamamad Aamir please post your code

Comment: @Qasim I have seen the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926995/activity-wont-render-randomly-shows-only-white-screen-on-samsung

removed the appcompact Activity but still randomly getting the white screen issue !