# FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I just migrated from eclipse to studio. I followed one blog to export project from eclipse to studio. The app working fine in lollipop and throwing the following error in pre lollipop devices.

Getting this error only in studio. not in eclipse.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:324)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.hsp.inventory.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
          //
          ......
          //
```

My gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
   // compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"

    compile project(':sliderLibrary')
    compile project(':camera')
    compile project(':volley')

    // Zxing library compile

    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-legacy:2.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'

}


android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hsp.inventory"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')


        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you want to take a look at my manifest and act_splash.xml. I will update here.

Any idea?

Comment: Switch to the latest version v 23 by updating your support repository. `compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23`

Comment: @Raghunandan I got this error after updating: `Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/rethinavel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Comment: Use AppCompat theme . Also update build tools to 23

Comment: @Raghunandan You are right sir

Comment: Have you rebuild the hole project?

Comment: @Zelldon Yes i did. Still getting the same error `FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout` in pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Do comment/mark the correct answer for people to get it right.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I faced the same issue and fixed it.
It is issue with Dex limit. Because the dex limit is reached, it creates two dex files. Lollipop knows how to read, pre-Lollipop has no idea unless you specify it in the `Application` class.

Please make sure following is in place:

in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
defaultConfig {          
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

*IMPORTANT* to support pre-Lollipop:

In Manifest, under the application tag,

```
<application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
</application>
```

Or if you have used your own `Application` class,
make your `Application` override `attachBaseContext` starting with

```
 import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
 import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

 public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
 // ......

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: This is the only thing which worked for me!! You saved my day, night, morning and everything!! Hearty thanks Ramesh!

Comment: It isn't necessary to change the name of your Application class in the Android Manifest. At least, it wasn't for me.

Comment: @mikbanUtah: "If you have written Application class, Have your Application override attachBaseContext"

Comment: @Ramesh "If you have written [a custom] Application class, Have[sic] your Application override attachBaseContext [and just make sure the Application class in the Android manifest is the same as the one you wrote]" 
It isn't clear that it's optional to do one or the other

Comment: Wow. Wow. Wow! This is amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used this code. But MyApplication class gave null Context. so I used          public class MyApplication extends Application   in MyApplication class. it is working perfectly. I up-voted this answer, thanks Ramesh & Rethinavel Pillai.

Comment: do i have to extend MultiDexApplication inside every java file i mean all activity and all fragments ??

Answer (score 1):

**Your logcat returns**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat

So update your support repository (Version 23)
And 
** For API 23:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Comment: After changing, I got this error `Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/rethinavel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  I am still getting the same exception. :-(

Comment: @RethinavelPillai Did you set your buildtoolversion 23  instead buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hsp.inventory"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }`

[SDK repository](http://s24.postimg.org/5y4p61c1h/Screen_Shot_2015_08_20_at_1_01_06_pm.png)

**Style :**
`<style name="MyAppCompatTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">`

_Anything wrong here? am still getting the same issue!_

Comment: <resources>
  <style name="MyAppCompatTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87449/discussion-between-rethinavel-pillai-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the gradle file you have posted here is top level gradle file,which contains stuff that should not be there. Replace your top level gradle file contents like below :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try your solution and revert you back!

Comment: I guess both are same. Doesn't it?

Comment: you tried it ? the part starting from apply plugin should not be there,it should be only in the inner build.gradle file.

Comment: Are you sure about it?

Comment: you tried all other things i guess , i am suggesting you because it happens when migrating eclipse project to android studio.

Comment: Actually i don't have good knowledge about gradle files. Honestly i don't know how to change the files as you mentioned. would you please guide me!

Comment: There will be a build.gradle file inside your app folder that is the inner gradle file and one in your project folder that is the outer or root gradle file . You have posted the root gradle file as I can see the comment on the top of file , so simply replace that file with contents as i have suggested and it may solve your problem,if not then the root gradle file still needs to be corrected like i have suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87454/discussion-between-rethinavel-pillai-and-amar).

Answer (score 0):

In the android documentation for [v7 appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) 
is a note:

> Note: This library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using
>   Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part
>   of this library's classpath.

I think thats your problem since you have comment out the line in your gradle:

```
   // compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
```

Add the line again and try to compile the project.

Also i see no `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0` line in your gradle

Comment: Even i followed your comment. I found the same error.

Answer (score 0):

May be a long shot, but ensure your images are under /res/drawable and not /res/drawable-v24
See this answer: [Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526417/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-imageview#answer-50112528)