# Binary file -NoClassDefFoundError: … R$styleable circlepageIndicator.java

Tags: android, exception, android-viewpager, android-inflate

error in *kitkat* device not in greater version of android.
after changing gradle file. library used for circle pager indicator. https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'}
**to** dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'}

Error is:

```
 Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.skedule.R$styleable
10-03 12:29:47.501 28314-28314/? E/AndroidRuntime:     
 at com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator.<init>(CirclePageIndicator.java:93)
10-03 12:29:47.501 28314-28314/? E/AndroidRuntime:     
 at com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator.<init>(CirclePageIndicator.java:74)
 CirclePageIndicator.java(inside my project->java->viewpagerindicator package)

package com.viewpagerindicator;

public class CirclePageIndicator extends View implements PageIndicator {
private static final int INVALID_POINTER = -1;

private float mRadius;
private final Paint mPaintPageFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint mPaintStroke = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint mPaintFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mListener;
private int mCurrentPage;
private int mSnapPage;
private float mPageOffset;
private int mScrollState;
private int mOrientation;
private boolean mCentered;
private boolean mSnap;

private int mTouchSlop;
private float mLastMotionX = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
private boolean mIsDragging;


public CirclePageIndicator(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle);
}

public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (isInEditMode()) return;

    //Load defaults from resources
    final Resources res = getResources();
    final int defaultPageColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_page_color);
    final int defaultFillColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_fill_color);
    final int defaultOrientation = res.getInteger(R.integer.default_circle_indicator_orientation);
    final int defaultStrokeColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_stroke_color);
    final float defaultStrokeWidth = res.getDimension(R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_stroke_width);
    final float defaultRadius = res.getDimension(R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_radius);
    final boolean defaultCentered = res.getBoolean(R.bool.default_circle_indicator_centered);
    final boolean defaultSnap = res.getBoolean(R.bool.default_circle_indicator_snap);

    //Retrieve styles attributes
  `TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator, defStyle, 0);  //Error here`
```

Answer (score 0):

By reference of this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110859/fatal-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-r)

added

```
dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'} defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true}
```

and

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}`
```

finally got solution.