# How to resolve java.lang.VerifyError in android

Tags: android, verifyerror

I am getting VerifyError for method calling of paticular class Utility ,first it was working properly and suddenly its started giving run time error, it is working fine with   API lollipop and higher API , Here is my error logs.

```
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117): java.lang.VerifyError: com/package/projectname/utility/Utility
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at com.package.projectname.AppDelegate.onCreate(AppDelegate.java:36)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:153)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-08 12:25:07.655: E/AndroidRuntime(18117):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your Utility class and the method that gives VerifyError

Comment: see if the cases listed [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-verifyerror-how-to-solve-verifyerror) covers your situation.

Comment: @manish jain , for all methods its giving error, like printing log also

Comment: what is your app buildToolsVersion?

Comment: @manish jain  23 Marhsmallow

Comment: @GiteekaSawlani, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110859/fatal-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-r/32236382#32236382)

Comment: actually it was occurring for different reason, Utility class has detect finger print code that's why it was not compiling properly, Thanks for help :

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by placing gms library separately:

Before I have used :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

That above one line will take care of GCM and all google related libaries.But this one line cause a verifier error.On top of the verifier error you can see some gms related log.

After that I have added separately like this to fix this issue :

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'

 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'    // for gcm push notification
```

and also [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196015/error-on-some-devices-couldnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-measurement)