# how add Android project as library or add arr in android moudle project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I need to use a third-party SDK which must be added as aar or android project library.

I tried to unzip the aar and copy the /lib and /res files to my titanium android module project, but it didn't work.

the error looks like this:

[image]

The developer of the SDK tell me check out a link which is [FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110859/fatal-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-r)

I don't know how to solve it, hope someone could help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because Titanium is a Javascript cross platform tool to build native apps, you will need to write a wrapper to get a native functionality to work.

You can check out the [documentation how to this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Development+Guide) on the Appcelerator website.

Unfortunately you can't just drop in a native component.