# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am using Android studio 3.0
I am getting tired fixing this problem. the app does not execute it always show me this error Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView

this is my main_activity.xml, I have changed my xml I used ConstraintLayout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.razoo.mywages.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="517dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/doctor" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/step1btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:onClick="nextPage"
    android:text="@string/button3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
    tools:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    tools:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    tools:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/button3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    tools:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    tools:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

java code for main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);//the error point here
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.step1btn);


}
public void nextPage(View view){
    Intent StartNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(StartNewActivity);

  }
 }
```

this is the full log,

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.razoo.mywages/com.example.razoo.mywages.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:387)
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2188)
                  at com.example.razoo.mywages.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:387) 
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2188) 
                  at com.example.razoo.mywages.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704) 
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.razoo.mywages:drawable/doctor" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060054 a=-1 r=0x7f060054}
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2431)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2371)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:387) 
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2188) 
                  at com.example.razoo.mywages.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Comment: There might be a problem with your `@drawable/doctor` . Show the full error log please.

Comment: use android:Src instead of app:srcCompact

Comment: you can get information about app:srcCompat and android:src, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc)

Comment: I used android:src , it gives me an error

Comment: so what is `doctor.*` file placed in one of `drawable*` folder?

Comment: doctor file is an jpg file

Comment: press Ctrl and click on "@drawable/doctor" to open it and double check it

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.razoo.mywages:drawable/doctor" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060054 a=-1 r=0x7f060054}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some SVGs sources seem to not be fully supported. Add below line within your activity's onCreate() method:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

and make sure you use below as attribute to your ImageView in your xml file:
app:srcCompact instead of android:src to define your image.

Comment: the doctor image is it a png file or vector?

Comment: it is a jpg file

Comment: The error is probably with the image, replace it with a working image and see if it shows.

Comment: yes, I change the image and it works. But why that image does not work? How to check the image?

Comment: Oh, I know why I was putting it in other drowable folder

Comment: you can use batch drawable plugin to import images. it will help you alot!!

Comment: xml file: app:srcCompat instead of android:src to define your image.

Comment: using  app:srcCompact  image is not shwon on de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView??

Comment: `app:srcCompat` instead of `app:srcCompact`

Answer (score 42):

In Android Studio version 3.0.0 and above, once we try to add images to drawable folder, it will ask you to 'Choose Destination Directory'. At that time, choose `drawable` instead of `drawable-v24`.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Keep Coding........ :)

Comment: yes,this is the main reason for that error thanks its helped

Answer (score 29):

don't paste your image in drawable(v-24), paste it into the drawable folder
and clean the project and then run it will work.

Comment: Can you describe root cause of this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

Solution for this kind of problem: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView

Solution:

1. Check Your Image Folder, whether the image file is in Drawer or Drawer-24 or not. Example Here

[Firebase image file is in Drawer-24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GO8F.png)

2. If image file is in drawer-24, **Right Click** the File and select **Refactor** and then click **Move**
3. Then remove the word "-24"  and Click OK and RUN again.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhNEy.png)

DONE.

Answer (score 2):

Well in my case it was crashing in only release builds because of proguard, so after i have added this line:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

in file `proguard-rules.pro`, the crash has been resolved.

Comment: What if you install AndroidX?

Comment: Same problem but not yet fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:src="@drawable/doctor"` in your ImageView

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this problem occur when we paste image from explorer to drawable folder then it ask weather to copy drawable or drawable-v24 and if you have pasted images in both directory structures, or have one more images with different directory structure then it will show this error, make sure to copy image only in 'drawable' directory structure :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the option in the accepted answer check if the vector is in the in the "drawable-anydpi" folder. Moving it to the "drawable" folder fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`.
It works in android studio 3.0