# App crash on API level 23 using app:srcCompact(using VectorDrawable)

Tags: android, android-layout

I was used vectorDrawable image . The app is crash on API level 23 and getting the error inflating class image. Anyone can tell me why this happened and why this error is come.

Comment: Test case add `defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }` in your **`build.gradle`** file

Comment: use android:src instead of app:srcCompat

Comment: defaultConfig { vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true } i was added in build gradle file.again same error its come .                                                          app build gradle :  vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true                           implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
     implementation "com.android.support:design:27.0.2"

Comment: Are you inflating that image inside an ImageView? if yes try using android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

Comment: i was try this.getting error : Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

Comment: my xml Imageview :  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSelectPhoto"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/select_photo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526417/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-imageview

Comment: thank you,   above stackoverflow link is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your application

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```