# Why is my app not running on an older device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

My app works fine on android Nougat and Oreo but not running when I want to open in a lower version like the lollipop.

I have set minSdkVersion 15 although not working.

Please let me if you find anything that is causing the problem. I am quite new at android app developing that's why not understanding what is wrong here. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Here below is my `build.gradle` code:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.internexia.app.gemsv1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-29 16:28:59.155 5887-5887/com.internexia.app.gemsv1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.internexia.app.gemsv1, PID: 5887
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.internexia.app.gemsv1/com.internexia.app.gemsv1.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.internexia.app.gemsv1.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.internexia.app.gemsv1:drawable/gems" (7f070065)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070065 a=-1 r=0x7f070065}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.internexia.app.gemsv1.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
01-29 16:28:59.158 5887-5900/com.internexia.app.gemsv1 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1597(218KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1057KB/2MB, paused 1.182ms total 139.996ms
01-29 16:33:59.849 5887-5887/com.internexia.app.gemsv1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5887 SIG: 9
```

Please help me if you know what's wrong here or any other suggestions.

Comment: check your logcat output for error, post the error stacktrace here.

Comment: please add stack trace error you are using the latest code just.

Comment: Added just now @KaranMer

Comment: Check Please @TanveerMunir

Comment: are you using vector graphics with imageview?

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.internexia.app.gemsv1:drawable/gems" (7f070065)  is not a Drawable` <= This said you're using vector drawable in `ImageView`, which is not supported in api < 21. Just follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc)

Comment: @KaranMer in ImageView I have used png files

Comment: or you might have properties in drawable which might not be supported in lower versions.

Comment: please add the layout of Home activity as well

Comment: check the xml code...your logcat is showing the error (Inflate Exception) or post your relatable xml code

Comment: I am using few drawable that is created by shape like,      
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>    is it causing the problem guys?

Comment: @RehanSarwar please add XML and java file also.

Comment: @RehanSarwar please have look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526417/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-imageview)

Comment: Hi, could you please add the XML file of same activity. So, that it is better to give solution.

Comment: I resolved this exception when moving all image file in drawable v-24 folder to drawable folder.

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions, I really appreciate it. Finally i have fixed the problem by following @Dhaval suggestion. I moved all the file from drawable v24 to drawable folder.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: Let me add it as an answer so others can easily get the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer all image files from `drawable-v24` folder to `drawable` folder.

Error will go away and it will work properly if you simply move the files.

Answer (score 0):

Some SVG sources seem to not be fully supported. Add below line within your activity's `onCreate()` **method:**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

And make sure you use below as attribute to your ImageView in your **XML file:** `app:srcCompact` instead of `android:src` to define your image.

Comment: tried but didn't work. Needed to move the drawable v-24 file to drawable folder.

Comment: @RehanSarwar please add XML and java file