# Android App not opening in Marshmallow android version in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

In my android app, My app gets opened in OS version of Android Pie but in Marshmallow not gets opened. First layout is opened but when second layout is opening, it is showing like 'Unfortunately, Myapp has stopped' and also my app gets crashed. Is there any ways to get out of this hurdle?

**My Error Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: can you share the crash logs so that we can help you better?

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee Could you check the above one?

Comment: connect your phone to your laptop and check the log messages in the android studio

Comment: @RohitSuthar yes I checked it.... but is shows error in line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`

Comment: Look at the logcat output to get the error message and the stack trace. Copy the relevant code plus error into your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally got the solution. Check this ([Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526417/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-imageview/48260621#48260621))