# Rendering issue in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I have a rendering issue in main activity.? I cant complete the work without resolving

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

below is the logcat output for error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.isThemeAppCompat(RenderSessionImpl.java:1203)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.findStatusBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1066)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:209)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:319)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:644)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:586)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It may cause due wrong setting of the Theme. Aslo Make sure that Activity extends AppCompatActivity. Post ur style code or theme ur using

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     

    </style>

Comment: have you solved the issue

Comment: then post ur activity code

Comment: now the error is following class could not be found android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout - this is now the rendering issue

Comment: can you post ur error log

Comment: U add the support v 4 library ?

Comment: i have post my xml code above..do i want to post main activity.java

Comment: don't forget to add the support library

Comment: can post current log with now getting . I want to see the  Current log

Comment: is this??  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: Are you using android studio ? then post your dependencies

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
}

Comment: add this to line to the dependencies    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1' sync and try

Comment: ya  done but ,but still rendering problem

Comment: following class could not be found android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout - this is now the rendering issue

Comment: please check this link it my help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614538/crash-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rlayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may cause due wrong setting of the Theme. Also Make sure that Activity extends AppCompatActivity. Change the theme to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> </style>`

add this to line to the dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

sync