# I encounter some issues using parse on some of my Android devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, compiler-errors, mobile-devices

I encounter some issues with parse regarding the device I'm running my project on.

First I tried to make Parse work on my project but I always had some issues regarding the device I was using, so I decided to take the ParseStarterProject ([here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new)).

I opened build.gradle with Android Studio and after checking that it was working on my two Android devices, I modified the AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle files to fit with my first project.

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
  ~ All rights reserved.
  ~
  ~ This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
  ~ LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
  ~ of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
  -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:largeHeap="true"
package="com.parse.starter">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"         />

<application
    android:name=".StarterApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme">
    >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common     to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
}

ext {
compileSdkVersion = 23
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

minSdkVersion = 16
targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

Build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}



android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.parse.starter"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

}

dependencies {
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.2'

compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
compile 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.0.3'
}

/* Uncomment if you enable ProGuard and you want to automatically upload symbols on build.
parse {
  applicationId "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
  masterKey "YOUR_MASTER_KEY"

 // Make symbol upload automatic. Otherwise, use e.g. ../gradlew    parseUploadSymbolsDebug;
  uploadSymbols true
}
*/
```

If I run the app on my OnePlus One, Android 5.1.1 (Cyanogen OS 12.1-YOG4PAS1N0), it works like a charm.
On my LG BELLO, Android 4.4.2, it doesn't run and I have the following

StackTrace :

```
10-22 15:11:06.951 26337-26337/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode

10-22 15:11:06.951 26337-26337/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17145: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-22 15:11:06.951 26337-26337/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-22 15:11:06.965 26337-26337/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-22 15:11:06.965 26337-26337/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e09da0)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 26337
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:307)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:254)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.starter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
10-22 15:11:06.967 26337-26337/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 15:12:45.993 26337-26337/com.parse.starter I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26337 SIG: 9
```

I noticed that the lines :
`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
 compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.2'`
seems to be at the origin of the issue.

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks :)

Here is the link to download directly my project :
http://we.tl/ZWy1c9ETx0

Jeff

Comment: Finally it was a Multidex issue and it worked after following the advices here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614538/crash-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rlayout/32549814#32549814