# Error :MenuItemCompat :getActionProvider item does not implement SupportMenuItem returning null

Tags: android, titanium

Hi I'm developing a Titanium Android module for video casting on Chromecast. I am creating menu programmatically. I'm using below code for this:

**Code for menu**

```
protected Menu newMenuInstance(Context context) {
    try 
    {
        Class<?> menuBuilderClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder");
        Constructor<?> constructor = menuBuilderClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);

        return (Menu) constructor.newInstance(context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Code for cast button:

```
@Kroll.method
public void castButtonLoader(){

    Menu menu= newMenuInstance(TiApplication.getInstance());

    int menuId= TiApplication.getAppRootOrCurrentActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("main", "menu",TiApplication.getInstance().getPackageName());
    new MenuInflater(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(menuId, menu);

    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem;    
    mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(menuId);

    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
}
```

It is returning given error:

> MenuItemCompat: getActionProvider: item does not implement SupportMenuItem; returning null

Can anyone please help why this error is raising?

Answer (score 0):

We are using the AppCompat library so it looks like this errors is telling you this will only accept menu items that also come from AppCompat:

```
android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
```

Comment: Could you please suggest what are the changes required for creating menu items from AppCompat in the given scenario. Thanks

Comment: Replace "com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder" with "android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder" and might need to import that class as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder