# Error: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I'm testing my project on MotoG (Lollipop 5.1) and a have problem that didn't have on XperiaT2 (KitKat 4.4). The error log is:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
```

I'm using android.support:design library but not instanciate the NavigationView, I tried to use

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

and

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

And didn't solve. Maybe the problem is related with a 
previously problem with support:appcompat library that this error happened when I tried use a 23.1.1 lower version

```
NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1
```

My actual Gradle configuration is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Please some help.

UPDATE

When I try to use

```
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

I have error to render the preview on android studio

```
Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

Even using my theme this way

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Comment: Did you try with buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' and compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'?

Comment: @Coeus I tried and appears this error again:  
NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try the following code and try again:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Or this:

```
gradle clean
```

According to some links I search around, may these do some tricks for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a solution (I've added below) from: [NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> EDIT:
>
> The solution that worked for me was (Using Proguard) to replace this:
>
> ```
> -keep class android.support.v4.** { *; } 
> -keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
>
> -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
> -keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
> ```
>
> with this:
>
> ```
> # Allow obfuscation of android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**
> # to avoid problem on Samsung 4.2.2 devices with appcompat v21
> # see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377
> -keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.** {*;}
> ```
>
> Credit goes to the google group: 
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377 #138
>
> Old answer (Temporary Workaround): It happens in a project where I use
>   an <s>spinner in the</s> ActionBar. My solution was to check for those
>   conditions and change the app flow:
>
> ```
> public static boolean isSamsung_4_2_2() {
>     String deviceMan = Build.MANUFACTURER;
>     String deviceRel = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
>     return "samsung".equalsIgnoreCase(deviceMan) && deviceRel.startsWith("4.2.2");
> }
> ```
>
> Then in the activity's onCreate method:
>
> ```
> if (isSamsung_4_2_2()) {
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_no_toolbar);
> } else {
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
> }
> ```
>
> As pointed out this is not a definitive solution, it is just a way to
>   allow users to have access to limited functionality while a more
>   permanent solution is found.

It seems to be a similar problem, so try it out and let me know if it works

EDIT: According to this Gihub issue, 
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify/issues/93
where you find this clue:

> There is no error when I am using com.android.support:design:22.2.0
>
> The error only occurs when I am using com.android.support:design:22.2.1

Downgrade you build-tools to 22.2.0 - it may be an Android problem.

Comment: Note: try to delete ProGuard. It's already deprecated by Google

Comment: I tried use -keep class on Proguard still didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your comment it's really for to delete Proguard? How do this?

Comment: #robindesu, please add your xml file

Comment: What xml do you mean? How a said I don't use NavigationView in fact. I can post the xml of main activity if help.

Comment: ok, nothing there. Look at your `build.gradle`. there are four libs with name starting with `com.android.support`. change all them version to one specific like `22.2.0`

Comment: try with version `23.01` - apply to every of these four dependencies

Comment: Didn't work. I guess that the problem It's some incompatibility between appcompat and design libraries. When I used 23 version of design, appears a error for to handle the preview (Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.). Even using parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" on my theme.