# Crash Report - NoClassDefFoundError: Android v7 support MenuBuilder

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, noclassdeffounderror, crash-reports

I have one crash report in my Google Developer Console which reports below error. From this error log, I don't see any reference to any classes from my App, rather seems like all the lines corresponds to Android libraries.

I know what NoClassDefFoundError means in general, but can't find a reason of that error with my current production. Never faced this issue in my device.

Now, how can I proceed with such errors? I have this error reported twice in last 6 months from Android 4.4 devices, I also use Android 4.4.2.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.getMenu(ActionMenuView.java:622)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.ensureMenu(Toolbar.java:822)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getMenu(Toolbar.java:814)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.getMenu(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:708)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.getMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:571)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:438)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:64)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit:** Seems like it was [a reported bug for android 4.2.2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377), however I am getting report from Android 4.4

Comment: You may want the solution in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder#comment56360103_26641388)

Comment: I saw that thread before posting, but that has some reference of the internal class file that was causing the issue (at com.[my-package-name].CustomActivity$5.onClick(CustomActivity.java:215)). For my case, I don't see the mention of any file that I wrote myself.

Comment: The issue is, if I can't reproduce the error, I won't know if that is resolved or not. So, first I need to to how to reproduce the error, for which I want to know exactly where the error was triggering.

Comment: I think you'll need a phone like a Samsung device that has a physical menu button

Comment: I do have Samsung Note II which is running on Android 4.4.2 and has physical menu button, but never faced that issue.

Comment: It's probably thrown in the background on the OS side and your logcat filter wouldn't show it if you are only inspecting the current app

Comment: Hmmm ... right .. but shouldn't it caused my App to crash? Because It doesn't (I use it a lot for testing, but never crashed for unknown reason)

Comment: Unless your Google Dashboard is showing the app is crashing, I don't think the app should crash, no. It is most likely an uncaught exception in the custom ROM that the vendor loaded into the device